# How to access self of class instance from a function assigned to a method?

Tags: python, class, methods

I assigned a custom function to a class method, however I can't seem to access self from within it.

```
class Handler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.func = None
        self.name = "Fourty Two"

    def run(self):
        if self.func: self.func()


def custom_func(self): # error: missing required argument: self
    print(self.name)

handler = Handler()
handler.func = custom_func
handler.run()
```

Is this sort of thing possible? How can it be done?

Comment: In run, do self.func(self) as your function requires an input.

Comment: @XinHuang Of course, how on earth did I not see that.. Thanks :D